# Count the number of words of particular length from a file

Tags: shell, text-processing

I've used the below command to count the number of words in a file:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < Filename | grep -c "WORD"
```

This returns the word list with counter. Now I want to count the number of words of a particular length. For example, given a file with these contents:

```
employee paresh emp employee jayesh hitesh
```

When I run the shell script with argument `6`, it should display/count words with 6 characters (`paresh`, `jayesh`, and `hitesh`, with count `3`). How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you grep for the regular expression `^.{6}$` it will return lines with exactly six characters:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < Filename | grep '^.\{6\}$'
paresh
jayesh
hitesh

$ tr ' ' '\n' < Filename | grep -c '^.\{6\}$'
3
```

Comment: Thanx for the support, it is running fine !! but can you please let me know about this : .\{6\} , that you have used with grep command.

Comment: what about \ sign before { and } ?? please

Comment: @Paresh Otherwise `grep` will look for `{` and `}` symbols, but not `6` repetitions of preceeding pattern.

Comment: Argh. I accidentally [deleted a comment trying to edit it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73322/editing-another-users-comment-deletes-it); sorry whoever's that was. @Paresh As that comment pointed out, it's to escape the braces so they're treated as part of the regular expression (`X{Y}` means "find the X character Y times"); without the escapes it searches for actual braces

Comment: thanx a lot for such helpful hints and answer. Thanx once again

Answer (score 3):

Also,

```
awk -v n=6 '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (length($i) == n) print $i}' file
```

or, with `tr`

```
tr ' ' '\n' file | awk -v n=6 'length($0)==n'
```

Comment: Or just use `NF`, you don't need to iterate to find the number of fields.

Comment: Sorry @ChrisDown, I don't understand your comment. Use NF where?

Comment: Oh, apologies, I misunderstood the intent of the question (misread as 6 *fields* rather than six *characters* in a field).

Comment: `awk '{ print length($NF) }' filename | sort | uniq -c` was useful to count word sizes in last column of a file. thanks